# Run Google Tag Manager script inside of a separate JavaScript file?

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

I wish to put the Google Tag Manager code that should be placed in the `<head>` of the .html page, in a separate JavaScript file.

Something along the lines of this: `<script src="/js/tagmanager.js"></script>`

*The code that should be placed in the head, provided by google:*

```js
<!-- Google Tag Manager -->
<script>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
})(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-XXXX');</script>
<!-- End Google Tag Manager -->
```

**How would I rewrite that code to run from the tagmanager.js script file, instead of the script that should be placed in the head? It would be nice if it would load async as well.**

Comment: Why do you want to load google tag manager in an external file. This snippet is already loading async. See the part: "async=true"

Comment: You're already creating an _async_ script as you described, so what is the problem?

Comment: Loading it in an external file would allow me the flexability of changing the code if google would ever make any updates to it. Instead of having to change the head of all pages, I would only have to change one file.

Comment: You can include that code snippet on the server, or at least include it in the main JS file instead of a seperate file

Comment: @AlonEitan thank you for the clarification. The website is very lightweight and the only code that will be used is the Tag Manager code. So the file could just as well be named main.js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place the contents of `<script>` into your tagmanager.js file:

```
(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
})(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-XXXX');
```

Then load it like this `<script async src="/js/tagmanager.js"></script>`

Comment: Why? What's the point in adding an extra request to a js file that all it does is creating another js file???

Comment: @AlonEitan because it's better to have all code in separate files in order to change them all in a batch in case I ever have to change them.

Comment: @TheLeggett, The code seems to work. One question before I mark the question as acceptable. How come it runs without me "calling it"?

Comment: @EliasWick the same reason it will work if you were to place it in the <head> directly. This code is written as a self-invoking anonymous function-it will run automatically.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. Many people doesn't seem to understand why I would want to have it in a separate script? Is there a reason to why that would be bad?

Comment: @EliasWick I would tend to agree with others that making another request for something like this probably isn't the best idea. Ordinarily I would put this directly into the <head> so that another full request doesn't need to be made for performance reasons.

Perhaps you could put this snippet into an include that simply gets required in your page templates? That way a user doesn't need to make additional http requests when they hit your page.

Comment: @TheLeggett, That sounds like a good idea. Are you referring to something like php includes?